# Pass a reference for a textfield to an object

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, textfield

I am working in Actionscript 3 here to control flash, however I think the problem is a generic object orientated one.

I have created a TextField in AS3, and this is displayed on the screen within the SocketExample class.

(It currently just says "hello")

This class creates a socket object that is used to read strings that are sent from an external IRC server over port 7001. I would like these strings to appear as text in the textfield but for some reason the socket class doesn't think that the refTextField exists.

AS3 Adobe Flash code:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.*;

    public class SocketExample extends Sprite {
        private var socket:CustomSocket;

        public function SocketExample() {

            var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
            myTextField.text = "Hello";
            addChild(myTextField);
            socket = new CustomSocket("localhost", 7001, myTextField);

        }
    }
}

import flash.errors.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.Socket;
import flash.text.TextField;

class CustomSocket extends Socket {
    private var response:String;

    public function CustomSocket(host:String = null, port:uint = 0, refTextField:TextField = null) {
        super();
        configureListeners();
        if (host && port)  {
            super.connect(host, port);
        }
    }

    private function configureListeners():void {
        addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
        addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
        addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
        addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
    }

    private function writeln(str:String):void {
        str += "\n";
        try {
            writeUTFBytes(str);
        }
        catch(e:IOError) {
            trace(e);
        }
    }

    private function sendRequest():void {
        trace("sendRequest");
        response = "";
        writeln("This String was sent from Flash.");
        flush();
    }

    private function readResponse():void {
        var str:String = readUTFBytes(bytesAvailable);
        response += str;
        trace(str);
        refTextField.text = str;
    }

    private function closeHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("closeHandler: " + event);
        trace(response.toString());
    }

    private function connectHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("connectHandler: " + event);
        sendRequest();
    }

    private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
        trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function socketDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
        trace("socketDataHandler: " + event);
        readResponse();
    }
}
```

The AS3 program requires a server to be running no port 7001, just for completeness here is a python script echo server that works.

Python code

```
# Echo server program
import socket
import sys

HOST = None               # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 7001              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = None

def startListening():
    print "starting to listen"

    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, socket.AF_UNSPEC,
                                  socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        try:
            s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        except socket.error as msg:
            s = None
            continue
        try:
            s.bind(sa)
            s.listen(1)
        except socket.error as msg:
            s.close()
            s = None
            continue
        break
    if s is None:
        print 'could not open socket'
        sys.exit(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected by', addr
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data: 
            break
        print data
        conn.send("I got that, over!")

    conn.close()
    print "connection closed"

while 1:
    startListening()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CustomSocket` class after this line:

`private var response:String;`

add this line:

`private var refTextField:TextField;`

And in `CustomSocket` constructor after this line:

`super();`

add this line:

`this.refTextField = refTextField;`

In this way your `CustomSocket` instance will keep a reference to your `TextField` instance.